# Counter: decrease method disregards boolean

Tags: java, boolean

I am trying to create a counter that holds a number that can be increased and decreased. The program also has a boolean check: when true, the counter cannot go negative. The program seems to run fine, but I cannot get the decrease methods (both decrease by one and decrease by input) to get the boolean right. It does not check the boolean value or something? I am new to Java and need help understanding what is wrong. The class is as follows:

```
public class Counter {

    private int value;
    private boolean check;

    public Counter(int startingValue, boolean check) {
        if (this.check = true) {
            this.value = startingValue;
            if (value < 0) {
                value = 0;
            }
        }
        if (this.check = false) {
            this.value = startingValue;
        }

    }

    public Counter(int startingValue) {
        this.check = false;
        this.value = startingValue;
    }

    public Counter(boolean check) {
        this.check = check;
    }

    public Counter() {
        this.value = 0;
        this.check = false;
    }

    public int value() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public void increase() {
        value++;
    }

    public void decrease() {
        if (this.check == true) {
            this.value--;
            if (value < 0) {
                value = 0;
            }
        } else if (this.check == false) {
            this.value--;
        }
    }

    public void increase(int IncreaseAmount) {
        if (IncreaseAmount >= 0) {
            this.value = value + IncreaseAmount;
        }
    }

    public void decrease(int DecreaseAmount) {
        if (DecreaseAmount >= 0) {
            this.value = value - DecreaseAmount;
        }
        if (check == true && value < 0) {
            value = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, if I was to execute a main program with this class like this for example:

```
Counter count = new Counter (2, true);
count.decrease();
count.decrease();
count.decrease();
```

What I want my program to do is to not go negative since the boolean check is true. Yet it does go to -1. Why is this?

Comment: `if (this.check = true)` should be `if (this.check == true)` or more simple `if (this.check)` Also don't forget to assign a value to `this.check` in your constructor: `this.check = check`.

Comment: You should call your boolean 'check' something like 'allowNegative' since it's easier to understand - but that's not your issue here.

Comment: Why downvote this? Perfectly fine question in my opinion (Edit: question was at -1 when I posted comment)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You fail to set the global variable `check` to `false`. You also used = instead of ==:

use:

```
public Counter(int startingValue, boolean check) {
    this.check = check;
    if (check == true) {
        value = startingValue;
        if (value < 0) {
            value = 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        value = startingValue;
    }    
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see I missed that detail. Thanks David for the suggested edit.

Comment: @ljgw This detail is main source of OP problem. Changing `if (this.check == false)` to `else` is just cosmetic change since (after correcting `if (this.check = true)` with `if (this.check == true)`) `check` value will not be changed.

Comment: While I do not understand what it means to "set a global variable check to false" (no disrespect, I just am very new to programming), your suggestion to add the line "this.check = check;" makes the program work the way I intended. Thanks!

Comment: @Pshemo he had an unused parameter in his constructor; the line `this.check = check` was the fix he needed in my opinion. (see also the OP's comment)

Comment: @Pshemo He also added the (most important) assignment in the first place. Apart from that: Readability matters!

Comment: @ljgw You're right. `this.check = check;` is also important part of your answer, my bad I didn't notice that it wasn't part of OP code. I didn't notice this most probably because I was stunned that while everyone was pointing out that OP is assigning value to `this.check` in `if` instead comparing it your code also contained this bug. Anyway +1 for correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use == to compare equality. The use of a single = sets the value.
Better yet, when checking the value of a boolean, just use the boolean. So instead of

```
if (someBool == true)
```

prefer

```
if (someBool)
```

Similarly, instead of

```
if (someBool == false)
```

prefer

```
if (!someBool)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean tests in your if statements need to use `==` for equality comparison in your constructor.

In your constructor's second if statement, you are assigning `check` to false.

Answer (score 0):

When performing boolean logic with a boolean, just use the boolean.

So instead of
"if (this.check == true)"  do  "if (this.check)"
and
"if (this.check == false)" do "if (!this.check)"

Also, you had "if (this.check = true)" for some, which assigns true to this.check.

You main issue is that you missed an assignment of an method parameter to the object variable "this.check = check; // I added this"

Compare your version with this:

```
public class Counter {

    private int value;
    private boolean check;

    public Counter(int startingValue, boolean check) {
        this.check = check; // I added this
        if (this.check) { //I changed this
            this.value = startingValue;
            if (value < 0) {
                value = 0;
            }
        } else { //and this
            this.value = startingValue;
        }

    }

    public Counter(int startingValue) {
        this.check = false;
        this.value = startingValue;
    }

    public Counter(boolean check) {
        this.check = check;
    }

    public Counter() {
        this.value = 0;
        this.check = false;
    }

    public int value() {  //good practice to use getVar and setVar, ie: getValue()
        return this.value;
    }

    public void increase() {
        value++;
    }

    public void decrease() {
        if (this.check) {  // you are not consistent with this.value VS value, which can be a confusing practise
            this.value--;
            if (value < 0) {
                value = 0;
            }
        } else {
            this.value--;
        }
    }

    public void increase(int increaseAmount) { //you had "IncreaseAmount", good practice to start vars with lower case
        if (increaseAmount >= 0) {
            this.value =  + increaseAmount;
        }
    }

    public void decrease(int decreaseAmount) {
        if (decreaseAmount >= 0) {
            this.value = value - decreaseAmount;
        }
        if (check && (value < 0)) {
            value = 0;
        }
    }

    public void print(){
        System.out.println("value:"+value+" check:"+check);
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Counter count = new Counter (2, true);
        count.decrease();
        count.print();

        count.decrease();
        count.print();

        count.decrease();
        count.print();

    }

}
```